# NET core Razor Pages Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I've set up Identity in a Razor Pages app and while the sign in is successful it doesn't persist which results in an endless redirect loop to the login page.

Here's the startup options:

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();


 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/BlogAdmin/Index");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/BlogAdmin/Login");

            });
```

Here i set the login URL

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/BlogAdmin/Login";

        });
```

This works in that it forces authentication at /BlogAdmin but after signin I notice the values in User are all null or default, in particular User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Here is the sign in logic (Login is a simple Razor Pages Page)

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(LoginViewModel.UserName);
            if(user != null)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, LoginViewModel.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    return Redirect("/BlogAdmin");
                }

            }

        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "user/pass not found");
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```

The result is always successful but when the /BlogAdmin route is hit it thinks I'm still unathenticated.

Am I missing a step?
Thanks

Comment: You may have missed the step of adding `app.UseAuthentication()` *before* `app.UseMvc()` in `Startup.Configure`.

Comment: doh! that was it - thanks @KirkLarkin